# Will the push/pull machine at the gym cause imbalance?

Tags: weightlifting, biceps, triceps

There is a machine at my gym that uses push on one arm and pull on the other. My concern is that one arm will have a bigger tricep than the other one and the other arm will have a bigger bicep than the other one, because of the different mechanisms being used at the same time. Is this going to cause imbalance?

Comment: Do you have a name or a picture? I'm curious about this machine.

Comment: Not if you're able to switch sides, but I've never heard of a "push/pull" machine. Does it look [like this](http://thumbs1.ebaystatic.com/d/l225/m/msjvgoKyQg4e_4gJre_mWBw.jpg)?

Comment: @ TestWell/Kneel Before Zod It looks more or so like this: https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.lifefitness.com%2Fstatic-assets%2Fimage%2Fproducts%2Fcommercial%2Fhammerstrength%2Fplateloaded%2Fgroundbases%2FCS-HSPL_GBT-L-hero.png&f=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you use it.

Yes, it can cause an imbalance (going by the picture you reference) if you overload one side or the other with weights consistently or you never switch and always push with the same hand and pull with the other.

However, I would imagine that it is meant to be used in alternating set fashion, to where you push with the left hand and pull with the right for one set, and then do the opposite for the second set. So no, if you are using it as it is probably meant to be used, then it won't produce an imbalance.

(BTW, the name for the machine you reference is the Hammer Strength Ground Base series, Twist Left or Twist Right.)

Comment: I imagine it's meant to hit / overload the anti-rotation stabilizers.

Comment: Actually, I think the official name is [Hammer Strength Plate-Loaded Combo Twist](https://www.lifefitness.com/facility/products/hammer-strength-plate-loaded/combo-twist).  Manual [here](https://www.lftechsupport.com/c/document_library/get_file?p_l_id=1691375&folderId=4969093&name=DLFE-97838.pdf).